# Defect leakage calculation

Tags: manual-testing, defect-tracking

I am a DBA by profession and never been part of any development or testing activity. It will be great if you can help me with the calculation

Calculate defect leakage in design where there are:

- 15 requirements
- 15 review defects
- 15 design defects
- 20 code review defects which include 10 design related defect captured during code review
- 20 system test defects

Comment: Defect leakage concerns bugs found in production. Your question is unclear.

Comment: @FDM Defects not found  QA but present is SIT is also defect leakage ?

Comment: What is SIT? Can you expand the abbreviation?

Comment: @dzieciou - System In Test. It means the same as AUT (application under test)

Comment: @KatePaulk There are so many acronyms for same thing. I am more used to SUT - System Under Test.

Comment: @FDM I don't find the question unclear. OP is looking for the leakage rate from design to test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of those questions where there is no absolutely correct answer.

If you are looking for all defects that leaked from design to test, then there are 20 because the defects captured (and presumably corrected) during code review don't count towards that number.

If you are looking for defects that were not captured and fixed during design, it would be the 10 found during code review, and possibly some or all of the 20 found in test depending on whether their root cause relates to design flaws.

Either way, this metric isn't particularly effective because what ultimately matters is how many defects leak to production, and how much they impact the customers.